# Resizable clipping path

Tags: wpf

I have an object: a ListView, this listview resizes when the window resizes. Now it also has a clipping path, but the clip does not resize with the rest. Is this even possible in WPF?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510920/rectanglegeometry-with-relative-dimensions-how

Comment: @Moozhe What should I look for? That has not much to do with clipping paths that resize..