# How to round the corners off of a TextBlock that's in a ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to round the corners off , from a TextBlock thats in a ScrollerViewer but i am struggling with the syntax and logic of how to implement this.

here is the scrollviewer with the TextBlock inside of it:

```
        `<ScrollViewer Height="238" Canvas.Left="18" Canvas.Top="17" Width="277" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock x:Name="outputTB" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" Background="#FFAAA9A9" FontSize="9" 
                <TextBlock.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX ="10"
                              RadiusY="10" 
                              Rect="0,0,Auto,Auto"/>
                </TextBlock.Clip>
            </TextBlock>
            <ScrollViewer.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX ="10"
                              RadiusY="10" 
                              Rect="0,0,277,238"/>
            </ScrollViewer.Clip>
        </ScrollViewer>`
```

I am not at all good with XAML in WPF C# so this is my last resort because I could not even find help from other websites and YouTube.

[errors I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie0gO.png)

Comment: There is no closing bracket ">" in the "<TextBlock" tag.

Comment: Aside from tag error which EldHasp pointed out, it is worth to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510920/3137337